# Uncaught ReferenceError : document is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm javascript beginner and I create this code behind to make an hover effect when a class is hover to affect another class.

But my problem still not here, my problem is when I debug my program I have this message of error in the debuger:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

I saw some many question on stackoverflow about this question but I don't understand the awnsers, for examples, what is usefull to install JSDom ? etc...

So I hope I'm not a silly to don't understand, and thanks to support my questions.

```js
const graphic = document.querySelector('.block1');
const audio = document.querySelector('.block3');
const zoomPro = document.querySelector('.zoom');
const zoomPerso = document.querySelector('.zoom2');

zoomPro.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    graphic.classList.add('hoverGraphic');
    audio.classList.add('unhoverAudio');
})

zoomPerso.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    graphic.classList.add('unhoverGraphic');
    audio.classList.add('hoverAudio');
})

zoomPro.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    graphic.classList.remove('hoverGraphic');
    audio.classList.remove('unhoverAudio');
})

zoomPerso.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    graphic.classList.remove('unhoverGraphic');
    audio.classList.remove('hoverAudio');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleM.css">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Animation.js">
            <Title>Zeryko - Portfolio</Title>
        </head>
<body>

<div class="mainblock">
    <!-- BOITE 1 -->
        <div class = "block1">
            <header>
                <a class = "zoom" href="PartieVisuelle.html">Professionnel</a>
            </header>
        </div>

    <!-- BOITE 3 -->
    <div class = "block3">
        <footer>
            <a class = "zoom2" href="PartieMusicale.html">Personnel</a>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- BOITE 2 -->
    <div class="BigBlock">
        <div class = "block2">
            <div class="Zeryko">Antoine DOUBLET</div>
            <div class="phrase">Developper & Artist</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your html code too please?

Comment: Show your html pls

Comment: I modify with my html code

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is designed to add event listeners to an HTML document. It only makes sense to run it embedded in an HTML document (using a `<script>` element) so that it is executed by the JS engine in a web browser when the HTML document is loaded.

Your error message, and mention of JSDOM, strongly suggests that you are trying to run the JS using Node.js. This doesn't make any sense.

Forget about Node.js. Add a `<script>` element to the HTML that includes a `src` attribute pointing at the URL of your JS. Use `defer` to make sure the page has finished parsing so the HTML elements you are searching for with `querySelector` exist in time.

```
<script src="....../yourjs.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: @expressjs123 — It's a placeholder.

Comment: I do the <script> and in my html it run well but still no for my JS but in the debuger it is write 
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\Animation.js

So i thinks my debuger still use nodejs ?

Comment: @Codiste — If you explicitly run node.js then yes, you are using node.js! If you want to debug it in the browser, open the developer tools built into your browser!

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks a lot for the time you give to my problem, have a nice day !